# Pass variable from function js to other function js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to pass and hold the value of store so that everytime user selects a different day, the value of store remains the same.

[store and day chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms9OP.png)

At first, I managed to show the result when I chose the store and the day values. However, when I changed to a different day, it doesn't hold the store value.

```
function changestore(){
      var filterstoregen = document.getElementById("filterstoregen").value;
      return filterstoregen;
      window.location.href='/new-retail/visitorreport?storename_='+filterstoregen;
 }


function changeday(){
      var storename2 = changestore();
      var filterday = document.getElementById("filterday").value;
      window.location.href='/new-retail/visitorreport?storename_='+storename2+'&dayname='+filterday;
 }
```

If I want to see the results of a different day, I need to choose again the store value first. This is because the chart becomes blank as if the store value is not selected.

Note that the functions written in the same file which is visitorreport.php.

Hopefully I have provided enough information to get some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your page refresh after choosing a new filter ? (I find your post very hard to understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than rebuilding the URL from scratch, you could take the page's current URL and only modify the parameter that was updated in the dropdown.

```
function changestore(){
      var filterstoregen = document.getElementById("filterstoregen").value;
      let params = (new URL(window.location)).searchParams;
      params.set('storename', filterstoregen);
      window.location.search = params.toString();
 }


function changeday(){
      var filterday = document.getElementById("filterday").value;
      let params = (new URL(window.location)).searchParams;
      params.set('dayname', filterday);
      window.location.search = params.toString();
 }
```